# MVC4 EF5 Update an bitmap image --save in db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, entity-framework, graphics, bitmap

After an edit, I must update a barchart stored in a db.
I have about 20hrs looking at examples but just put it together.
My class

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SCert { get; set; }
    public byte? Taskimage { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Task task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            // now create a new graph using the returned viewbag data

            var Mytopleft = 0;
            var Mytext = "";
            Bitmap mybmp = new Bitmap(400, 20);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mybmp);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 400, 20);
            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.OldLace);
            g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, 400, 20);
            // draw comma-delimited elements in multiple colors
            string[] chunks = Mytext.Split(',');
            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush[] brushes = new SolidBrush[] 
                {   new SolidBrush(Color.OldLace),          //removed 3 other brushes for clarity
                 };
            int c = 0;
            var tasks = db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Builder).Include(t => t.Lot);
            foreach (var titem in tasks.ToList())
            {
                if (titem.SStart == null)
                { c = 0; }
                else if (titem.SStart != null && titem.SEnd == null)
                { c = 1; }                             //removed 3 other cases for clarity
                // create a new rectangle displaced by offset and with color
                g.FillRectangle(brushes[c], Mytopleft, 0, 10, 20);
                Mytopleft += 10;
            }                
                               //write to folder as a test   this works  Gif is arbitrary.
                              //can't use c:\\lot1.bmp   -- can't write to root dir
            mybmp.Save("C:\\temp\\lot1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            mybmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

So after a date is changed, I modify the barchart and update the TaskImage image stored in the db.

The creation of mybmp works and writes a file to the temp folder as a test.

I've been trying for days to understand how to save the mybmp to TaskImage. I think part of my confusion is assignment, in my old days I would do something like mybmp= toarry(System.Drawing.Imageing.ImageFormat.Gif).  I don't think that works in MVC C#. I think the image is actually in System.Drawing.Image as it is being created and modified.

So in outline:       MVC4 EF5 code first
- save created image to memorystream????
- convert memorystream to byte array
- reference the byte[] to TaskImage field
- tell .State that we have a modification....... db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
- save changes..overwrite existing image.... db.SaveChanges();

I think this is the correct logic. I'm doing a complete redraw rather than modifying the existing image so I don't need to retrieve it first.
BTW after I get this working I will change the code to store TaskImage in a related table rather than the edited table here. I don't think that will change the structure of your answer.

There are many examples of retrieving and passing to view. I think I can handle that.

Stumped!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others here is working code
As with many things once you figure it out it's pretty simple this works. This write to a related table, hence the lottoupdate.

```
mybmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        ms.Close();
        var lottoupdate = db.Lots             //each task row contains the lotid to which
               .Where(i => i.LotID == lotID)  //it is associated. Find the LotID then
               .Single();                    // update the taskimage field in the lot class
         byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        lottoupdate.TaskImage = byteArray;
        db.Entry(lottoupdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I hope this helps someone else.
To retrieve this image and show in view see this question: **Image to Byte[] harder than thought 2 challanges**

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code:
**- save created image to memorystream????

- convert memorystream to byte array

- reference the byte[] to TaskImage field

- tell .State that we have a modification....... db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;

- save changes..overwrite existing image.... db.SaveChanges();**
Looks ok.

So why the code?

```
mybmp.Save("C:\\temp\\lot1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        mybmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Are you saving to file or EF table ?  Title says Save in Db.

In fact the "problem or error" isnt that clear.

Is this really a question. How to convert Image to byteArray and back ?
Since saving and retrieving records from a DB that have field of type Byte[] is not the issue right?
So I guess you need this

```
 public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // consider format
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        return image;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SCert { get; set; }
    public byte? Taskimage { get; set; } // <<<<<< make Byte Array ??????
}
My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Task task)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   


        // 
        // now create a new graph using the returned viewbag data
      Image graph = CreateImageFromViewBag(viewbag); // refactored out... 
      task.Image =  ImageToByteArray(graph);

       db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;


        db.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: I've seen the to and from but could not figure out how to take the "return" and write it to the TaskImage field in the EF table.

Comment: How to convert the principles to inline code. That is take the "return" and write it to the TaskImage field in the EF table. It seem that the line image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) saves the image to a ms. the ms.ToArray) converts it to the byte[]. Now I need the code to "assign" the .ToArray() to the TaskImage. Then I assume my db.Entry.... will update the record.@philsoady

Comment: Yes the issue is how to get from the memory stream to the db.save. Something like Task.TaskImage = ImageFromStream(ms.ToArray());    @phil